# How to use driver to load data and executors for processing and writing?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to use Spark structured streaming to watch a drop location that exists on the driver only. I do this with

```scala
val trackerData = spark.readStream.text(sourcePath)
```

After that I would like to parse, filter, and map incoming data and write it out to elastic.

This works well except that it does only work when `spark.master` is set to e.g. `local[*]`. When set to `yarn`, no files get found even when deployment mode is set to `client`.

I thought that reading data in from local driver node is achieved by setting deployment to client and doing the actual processing and writing within the Spark cluster.

How could I improve my code to use driver for reading in and cluster for processing and writing?

Comment: what if you copy the driver data to HDFS? Then you can process the files in parallel with spark and when finished delete them

Comment: Nice idea and that would work.How could I copy the files to hdfs and delete them afterwards using spark structured streaming?

Comment: So I would suggest the next: 1) to transfer your data into HDFS through a 3rd party tool from hadoop stack such as Flume 2) or even better use a Spark job to do the same with streaming (this should run as a deamon with [jobserver](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver)). So in the 2nd case your scala code should retrieve all files (maybe in parallel as well) and load them into spark dataframes which in return will store the data into HDFS 3) the last solution could a be a single daemon running this command recursively hadoop fs –copyFromLocal localfilePath hdfsPath :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible, but not recommended in Spark Structured Streaming in particular and in Apache Spark in general.

The main motivation of Apache Spark is to bring computation to the data not the opposite as Spark is to process petabytes of data that a single JVM (of a driver) would not be able to handle.

The driver's "job" (no pun intended) is to convert a RDD lineage (= a DAG of transformations) to tasks that know how to load a data. Tasks are executed on Spark executors (in most cases) and that's where data processing happens.

---

There are some ways to make the reading part on driver and processing on executors and among them the most "lucrative" would be to use [broadcast variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a read-only variable cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it with tasks. They can be used, for example, to give every node a copy of a large input dataset in an efficient manner. Spark also attempts to distribute broadcast variables using efficient broadcast algorithms to reduce communication cost.

---

One idea that came to my mind is that you could "hack" Spark "Streams" and write your own [streaming sink](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Sink.scala#L40) that would do `collect` or whatever. That could make the processing local.

Comment: Thanks @JacekLaskowski I agree with you as the fundamental of spark distributing work. Without structured streaming I could do a collect() or collectAsList() to get all the data to the driver and then „re-parallelize“ and distribute the data. With structured streaming I have no chance. I think I will have to „upload“ the data to hdfs to get it processed and streamed to elastic. Am I right with this?

Comment: Almost. I've just elaborated with another idea of writing a custom sink that would allow you doing pretty much everything local.

Comment: But my thing here is that I would like to do the reading locally and doing the processing and writing to the sink using the cluster.

Comment: Who's transfer the data to executors (aka cluster)? The only way a data could get transfered by Spark from the driver to executors is by means of broadcast variable. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have not tried or used broadcast in streaming context. Can I combine readStream with broadcast() only by writing my own steaming source? You wrote about writing my own sink but I thought writing my own source would make more sense.

Comment: Took @JacekLaskowski advice and load the files via "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal" to hdfs using a cron job. After that I can process the files using streaming regardless of whether the driver or workers are local or part of the yarn managed cluster.